# find values with a list of search parameters

Tags: c#, linq

In my example I'm having problems to add my search results to one list. I have to display multiple students wHich are in different locations. I am having problems with `.ToList()` in `foreach` statement. It only displays my students from last location.

Below is my code:

```
public void Search(IEnumerable<string> Location)
{ 
    Location.ToList();

    foreach (var l in Location)
    {
        var students = from s in db.Students
                       select s;                  

            students = students.Where(s => s.City.Contains(l));

        var searched = students.ToList();
        int custIndex = 1;
        Session["Students"] = searched.ToDictionary(x => custIndex++, x => x);
        ViewBag.TotalNumberStudents = searched.Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you display the students? What do you pass to your `View`?

Comment: in the line `Session["Students"] = searched...` you assign a _new_ dictionary in every iteration (for each location). you need to combine these dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you all, as I understand, I have to declare searched variable before foreach loop, and use Session["Students"]  and viewbag outside of foreach. But then I can't reach students.toList(). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem likely is caused because you keep replacing your `Session["Students"]` and `ViewBag.TotalNumberStudents`:

```
Session["Students"] = searched.ToDictionary(x => custIndex++, x => x);
ViewBag.TotalNumberStudents = searched.Count();
```

Hence, only the last `searched` in the end got passed.

Try to accumulate the result, then pass them at once to `Session["Students"]` and `ViewBag.TotalNumberStudents`

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code, `custIndex` is defined inside the loop and Session variable *overwrites* by next iteration, hence you notice only last `seached` results in the session.

You could just do this.

```
int custIndex =1;
Session["Students"] = Location.SelectMany(l=> db.Students.Contains(l))
                              .ToDictionary(x=>custIndex++, x=>x);

ViewBag.TotalNumberStudents = searched.Count();
```